# Panel: Network Overview

Tags: cytoscape

In the network overview panel on the left (Cytoscape 3.8.2, desktop), is it possible to change positions of the indicated (sub-)networks?

Before:

Network

1. Sub-network

**3.** sub-network

2. Sub-network

After:

Network

1. Sub-network
2. Sub-network
3. Sub-network

example:
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, there is no easy way to reorder the entries in the network panel.  It would probably be a useful feature, though...

-- scooter